# Linkedin API returns NULL : IPhone SDK

Tags: api, ios4, linkedin-api

I am using Linkedin iphone SDK https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

It was working fine

But from this week its not giving proper response of API request

I am requested for API /v1/people/~/network/updates

It was working fine and was returning updates Array in function

```
- (void)linkedInEngine:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine requestSucceeded:(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier withResults:(id)results
```

But from this Monday its not returning the **results Array**

it logs

*NSLog(@"++ LinkedIn engine reports success for connection %@\n%@", identifier, results);*

***++ LinkedIn engine reports success for connection 70621202-C081-4B60-8463-5FB2664A2ECD
(null)***

means API not returning updates

What is the issue.

**EDIT**
When I am updating status on using API **/v1/people/~/current-status** then same null reply but my status was updated on linkedin

**Amit Battan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its was temporary API issue from LinkedIn side